# using microsoft graph api to retrieve chat members

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

Following this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp

I tried using :

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var members = await graphClient.Me.Chats["{id}"].Members
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

However, visual studio gives IUserRequestBuilder doesn't not contain a definition for Chats.

Microsoft.Graph version used from NuGet packages 3.8.0

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chats endpoint i believe is in the beta endpoint. that means you should be using in vs, the nuget package microsoft.graph.beta
and not microsoft.graph.

Comment: yep the NuGet package needs to be added from the package manage console Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Beta -Version 0.19.0-preview